# How to save state of a frame that's inside a page?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

The question is, when a XAML page is used inside another XAML page, how can I load saved states of both pages?

**Details**

To make my `ProfilePage.xaml` simple and reusable, I've created it separately and use it inside pivot of the `MainPage.xaml` (is that a good approach?)

```
<Grid>
    <Pivot>
        <PivotItem>
            <Grid/>
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem>
            <Frame x:Name="ProfileFrame"/>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

When `MainPage` is loaded, `ProfileFrame` navigates to `ProfilePage.xaml`:

```
this.ProfileFrame.Navigate(typeof(ProfilePage), parameter);
```

Each page saves state normally using NavigationHelper

```
private void NavigationHelper_SaveState(object sender, SaveStateEventArgs e)
{
    e.PageState["collection"] = collection;
}
```

The problem is that the `MainPage` saves state, and then when come back again to the `MainPage`, `ProfilePage` needs to be created new, without loading the old saved data.

How can I load state of `ProfilePage.xaml` when it is used inside frame control of the `MainPage.xaml`?

Comment: Could I first confirm that what `NavigationHelper` you are using here? In windows 10 uwp app there is not such a class by default, did you copy it from a windows 8.1 template? Does it same with [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/XamlUIBasics/cs/AppUIBasics/Common/NavigationHelper.cs) inside the sample?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT interestingly I've copied it exactly from that sample! yes that is.